# The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

```html
import 'package:learnflutter/questionMain.dart';
import 'questionButton.dart';

class mainQuestions extends StatelessWidget {
  List aQuestions;
  int questionIndex;
  Function answerQuestion;

  mainQuestions(
      {required this.aQuestions,
      required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          aQuestions[questionIndex]['aQuestion'],
        ),
        ...(aQuestions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
        })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

****My problem is that it keeps saying:
The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
I am new to flutter is anyone able to help me? Thanks!
(Didn't mean to use HTML just not sure how to add code**)**

```html
...(aQuestions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what will fix is is extracting the answers into a separate variable, together with calling `toList` at the end. This didn't raise any compilation errors for me:

```
List<Widget> _answers() {
  List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> answers = aQuestions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>;
  return answers.map(answer => Answer(answerQuestion, answer)).toList();
}

return Column(
  children: [
    Question(aQuestions[questionIndex]['aQuestion']),
    ..._answers(),
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The map function returns an iterable, not a list. That is why after mapping, you have to convert it to a list by calling the toList() function on it.
Here's how:

```
import 'package:learnflutter/questionMain.dart';
import 'questionButton.dart';

class mainQuestions extends StatelessWidget {
  List aQuestions;
  int questionIndex;
  Function answerQuestion;

  mainQuestions(
      {required this.aQuestions,
      required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          aQuestions[questionIndex]['aQuestion'],
        ),
        ...(aQuestions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>)
            .map((answer) {
          return Answer(answerQuestion, answer);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```